# Simple General Purpose Parser Implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

This is an implementation of a general Purpose Parser/Matcher that can operate on any input stream of objects and will return all possible combinations.

In this case I do not value performance that much, but if you find something major, tell me.

This does by design no optimizations before parsing to be easily editable.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Iterator, TypeVar, Iterable, Generic, List

T = TypeVar('T')


class Rewindable(Iterator[T]):
    """
    A Rewindable Wrapper around an iterator the allows for 'rewinding'
    the iterator by reloading an old state
    """

    def __init__(self, iterator: Iterable[T]):
        self._iterator = iter(iterator)
        self._index = 0
        self._cache = []

    def __next__(self) -> T:
        self._index += 1
        while self._index > len(self._cache):
            self._cache.append(next(self._iterator))
        return self._cache[self._index - 1]

    def get_state(self) -> object:
        """Returns an object indicating the current position
        that can be reloaded via `load_state`"""
        return self._index

    def load_state(self, state: object):
        """Reloads a state returned by `get_state`"""
        assert isinstance(state, int)
        self._index = state


IN = TypeVar('IN')
OUT = TypeVar('OUT')


class Parser(Generic[IN, OUT]):
    """
    Base class for Parser which match pattern in an rewindable
    input stream and return all possible matches
    """

    def parse(self, in_stream: Rewindable[IN]) -> Iterator[Iterator[OUT]]:
        """
        Matches the pattern in the Rewindable stream `in_stream`
        Returns an Iterator over all possible matches (also iterator)
        The implementation must insure that `in_stream` is reset
        after StopIteration is thrown
        """
        raise NotImplementedError


class DirectParser(Parser):
    """
    A Parser that matches the value `expected` and yields `result` in response
    """

    def __init__(self, expected: IN, result: OUT):
        self.expected = expected
        self.result = result

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.expected!r}>"

    def parse(self, in_stream: Rewindable[IN]) -> Iterator[Iterator[OUT]]:
        state = in_stream.get_state()
        try:
            n = next(in_stream)
        except StopIteration:
            return
        if n == self.expected:
            yield iter((self.result,))
        in_stream.load_state(state)


class ORParser(Parser[IN, OUT]):
    """
    A Parser that matches any Parser of `sub_parser` and returns all possible results of each one
    """

    def __init__(self, sub_parser: List[Parser[IN, OUT]]):
        self._sub_parser = list(sub_parser)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '(' + '|'.join(repr(sp) for sp in self._sub_parser) + ')'

    def parse(self, in_stream: Rewindable[IN]) -> Iterator[Iterator[OUT]]:
        for sp in self._sub_parser:
            yield from sp.parse(in_stream)


class ANDParser(Parser[IN, OUT]):
    """
    A  Parser that matches the Parsers of `sub_parser` and returns all possible combinations
    """

    def __init__(self, sub_parser: List[Parser[IN, OUT]]):
        self._sub_parser = list(sub_parser)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '(' + ' '.join(repr(sp) for sp in self._sub_parser) + ')'

    def parse(self, in_stream: Rewindable[IN]) -> Iterator[Iterator[OUT]]:
        iterator_stack = [self._sub_parser[0].parse(in_stream)]
        try:
            result = [tuple(next(iterator_stack[0]))]
        except StopIteration:
            return
        skip = False
        while len(iterator_stack) > 0:
            if not skip:
                if len(iterator_stack) == len(self._sub_parser):
                    assert len(result) == len(self._sub_parser)
                    yield (v for t in result for v in t)
                else:
                    iterator_stack.append(self._sub_parser[len(iterator_stack)].parse(in_stream))
                    result.append(())
            try:
                result[-1] = tuple(next(iterator_stack[-1]))
                skip = False
            except StopIteration:
                skip = True
                result.pop()
                iterator_stack.pop()


class RepeatingNGParser(Parser[IN, OUT]):
    """
    A Parser that matches `min_count` to `max_count` repetitions of Parser `parser`
    and returns all possible combinations (Non Greedy, matches as few repetitions as possible first
    `max_count` can be `None` to indicate that the repetition can be infinite
    """

    def __init__(self, parser: Parser[IN, OUT], min_count: int, max_count: int = None):
        self.parser = parser
        self.min_count = min_count
        self.max_count = max_count

    def parse(self, in_stream: Rewindable[IN]) -> Iterator[Iterator[OUT]]:
        count = self.min_count
        if count == 0:  # Special case Optional matching
            yield iter(())
            count = 1
        while self.max_count is None or self.max_count > count:
            iterator_stack = [self.parser.parse(in_stream)]
            try:
                result = [tuple(next(iterator_stack[0]))]
            except StopIteration:
                return
            skip = False
            any_result = False
            while len(iterator_stack) > 0:
                if not skip:
                    if len(iterator_stack) >= count:
                        assert len(result) == len(iterator_stack)
                        any_result = True
                        yield (v for t in result for v in t)
                    else:
                        iterator_stack.append(self.parser.parse(in_stream))
                        result.append(())
                try:
                    result[-1] = tuple(next(iterator_stack[-1]))
                    skip = False
                except StopIteration:
                    skip = True
                    result.pop()
                    iterator_stack.pop()
            count += 1
            if not any_result:
                return
```